# Is my BSOD related to SSD or memory?

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, bsod, minidumps

So I've been having a TON of BSOD's lately, and finally have been able to get dump files to save when my PC crashes. Previously, the system restarted too fast for me to read the stop code, and would reboot with something along the lines of: "NO BOOT DEVICE DETECTED. SELECT BOOT DEVICE OR PRESS A KEY TO CONTINUE". So I'd reboot, and everything works absolutely fine, no problems whatsoever, it always resolves after the first reboot. This cycle repeats, causing some hair pulling and many hours spent on google, in addition to some lost work files.

This has occurred about 40 times over the last 3 month(according to reliability history) , and the frequency just jumped from 1 per week to around 4-5 a DAY. I thought the problem was my HDD so I bought a new samsung SSD, which did not solve the problem (but it sure is nice and quick ;) ) I’ve also noticed in reliability history that my wireless adapter will occasionally stop working, possibly related? 
Here is one such report in reliability viewer:

> Problem Event Name:    LiveKernelEvent
>   Code:  144
>   Parameter 1:   3003
>   Parameter 2:   ffff8304fce1b6c8
>   Parameter 3:   40010000
>   Parameter 4:   0
>   OS version:    10_0_17134
>   Service Pack:  0_0 
>   Product:   768_1
>   OS Version:    10.0.17134.2.0.0.768.101
>   Locale ID: 4105

The most recent BSOD (MEM_MANAGEMENT)  produced a dump file, and analysing it finds the following:

```
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000006001, The subtype of the bugcheck.
Arg2: ffffffffc000000e
Arg3: 0000000001a10000
Arg4: ffffad8d76960010

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_6001

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  MemCompression

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

BAD_PAGES_DETECTED: a8ae

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80169e0d473 to fffff80169dc80c0
```

The laptop I’m on is an Asus X556L, Intel i5-5200@2.20 gHz, 6 GB ram, 64-bit windows 10. Any suggestions how to resolve this particular problem? If I’ve missed any information let me know and I’ll update it.

*Edit*:
Could this be the physical connection of the SSD to the motherboard? Since replacing the drive made no difference, maybe the drive connections are preventing proper interfacing. This seems somewhat plausible except for that fact that the drive has no trouble during use, easily reaching read/write speeds of 400MBps (there is no cable, it plugs directly into a small chip that then connects to the MB)

**Comments**
-Yes, this is the only SSD in the system. It's a few months old, and has no problems indicated in either Samsung's built in SMART test or the diskcheckup utility.
Bluescreenview - this looks useful, will use later today
- Performed a memtest with windows memory test, no problems there either. I'll do an indepth test later tonight with memtest86 and post any interesting results. It may be of note that I can use essentially all 6 GB of ram with no issues, such as when Fortnite and Microsoft Edge are running simultaneously(uses 5.8 GB ram for hours on end, performance is fine)

Comment: Is this the only HDD/SDD in the system?

Comment: Use bluescreenview to see all of your BSODs: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: Use memtest86 to test your memory: https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: Look for S.M.A.R.T. errors with this: https://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm

Comment: If you suspect your memory you need to test your memory with the appropriate tool.  If you encounter no errors then you know it's not the memory.

Comment: To me it screams "RAM issue" since replacing your drive did not fix the issue, so I agree with using memtest86, and also try with taking out one or more of your RAM sticks and see if it occurs. I would also try to reproduce the issue using a RAM stress tester to see if it occurs when stressing the RAM, or if its another issue entirely.

Comment: @BillDoe yes, updated the post.  Also interesting to note, the drivers for SpeedFan crashed when I ran a driver check, no BSOD's since uninstalling it:)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1a--memory-management).

You can see that, depending on "Parameter 1" (which is Arg 1 in the output you've included in your question) provides a lot of information.

- Microsoft says some of these are strong indications of hardware errors.
- Page files and therefore your SSD are involved in memory management, bui nothing in the above reference seems to suggest it could be triggered by an I/O error.
- The rest are errors that can happen in drivers or other kernel-level services.

`MemCompression` would certainly be a kernel-level thing, but it's not going to be something writing to disk.

Especially since you've already tried a different SSD, the two things left to eliminate are drivers/kernel-level software and then the hardware itself (motherboard or RAM).

- Make sure UEFI is at latest version.
- Make sure system is not overheating.
- Make sure power supply can handle all components in your system (search for a PSU calculator).
- Ensure all latest Windows and driver updates are installed.  Driver updates can be obtained from manufacturer.  If you have a discrete graphics card, ensure that driver is the latest.
- Replace RAM, PSU, motherboard in that order.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it looks like it might have been caused by speedfan. No problems since uninstalling it

Comment: Speedfan installs a device driver to work.  Might be incompatible with Windows 10 memory compression or something it does to access sensors doesn't work well with it.